# Org-mode how to write addr block and export to pdf correctly

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Try to get a kind of letter with the sender on left side and the receiver on right side.  I can use "indent to" that's ok in Emacs but  when exporting to html or pdf the indentation characters are swiped out .. Can someone tell me how to get this working in pdf, html or odt format ?
Thk

Org-mode with "indent to" picture ..
[image: Emacs Org-mode]
Pdf result ..
[image: Pdf export]

Comment: Can you develop more about non proportional spacebar.  How to achieve that in Emacs.. ? Thk

Comment: For Emacs related questions, you are likely to get better response at Emacs Stackexchange.  I have re-posted your question at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72339/org-mode-how-to-write-addr-block-and-export-to-pdf-correctly.  I will post my answer in there.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced this question in Emacs Stackexchange, and posted my response there.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72340/31220.